# Applying DISTINCT to multiple columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say I have a table of: `order_id`, `agent_name`, `order_amount`.

| order_id | agent_name | order_amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Justin | 500 |
| 2 | Justin | 500 |
| 3 | Justin | 1000 |
| 4 | Justin | 1000 |
| 5 | Pablo | 750 |
| 6 | Dinesh | 500 |

How would I write a query to apply DISTINCT not only on `agent_name` but also on `order_amount`? Basically want it to return [Justin, 500] and [Justin, 1000] once only. Is it something like the below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT agent_name, 
DISTINCT order_amount
FROM table
```

Comment: DISTINCT operates on rows, not columns. Remove the 2nd DISTINCT.

Answer (score 0):

The query goes like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT agent_name, order_amount FROM table
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: I see, then I guess my question should have been the other way around. How would I only apply DISTINCT onto 1 column instead of all columns? So lets say to only show Justin 1 time regardless of `order_amount`?

Comment: Sure, this will be a completely different query then. SELECT  agent_name, min(order_amount)/max(order_amount) FROM table group by agent_name; This makes sure we have unique agent names and order_amount will be based on your logic, you need max order amount or min... Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT agent_name, order_amount
FROM table
```

`DISTINCT` applies to all columns listed in select.

Comment: I see, then I guess my question should have been the other way around. How would I only apply DISTINCT onto 1 column instead of all columns? So lets say to only show Justin 1 time regardless of `order_amount`?

Comment: @Katsu, Depends on what exactly you are looking for. If you want only `agent_name` then `SELECT DISTINCT agent_name FROM table`. If `agent_name` and any of `order_amount` then `SELECT DISTINCT agent_name, MIN(order_amount)
FROM table GROUP BY agent_name
`